# Spring batch in wildfly 8.x

Tags: spring, admin, spring-batch, wildfly

Im looking for something that is similar to Spring Batch in which one have the Admin part out of the box, except i would like it to use components thats already in wildfly 8.x.
We have a lot of schedules that should be configurable and would like to create
some admin page for each running wildfly, but it would be extremely nice to find something that runs out of the box with wildfly and if possible without having to integrate spring into wildlfly.

Does such (hidden gem) component exist ??
I've tried to google, but found nothing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Batch API is part of Java EE 7, implemented in WildFly by [JBeret](http://jberet.gitbooks.io/jberet-user-guide/content/).

This is "just" an API and does not include a user interface.

Having said that, any UI for your batch jobs is bound to be application specific, and it really isn't hard to write a couple of JSF views to manage batch jobs.

Comment: Just to add in WildFly 10 you can start, stop and restart batch jobs in deployments via management operations. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Batch+%28JSR-352%29+Subsystem+Configuration#Batch%28JSR-352%29SubsystemConfiguration-DeploymentResources

Comment: The apache project batchee provides a GUI to show batch jobs simply by adding a maven dependency  
  
  
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.batchee</groupId>
 <artifactId>batchee-servlet-embedded</artifactId>
 <version>0.2-incubating</version>
</dependency>
  
[apache batchee](http://batchee.incubator.apache.org/)